# Trying to write shiny app data (csv) to a folder on desktop. shiny Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

Tags: shiny

I am very new to shiny and am trying to make create a survey where the data submitted will be downloaded to a folder on my desktop.

I am using this article as a guide and basically have the exact same code but have used the "locally stored" option for saving the data.

When I ran app, files were being saved to the correct folder on my desktop but when I published on shinyapps.io and tried submitting responses using the url, I get the error :
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")
and
cannot open file 'C:/Users/tolson/Desktop/Shiny/1524841166_57ededaa8d9c46a94f5bb4a352412699.csv': No such file or directory
2018-04-27T14:59:26.847383+00:00 shinyapps[331397]: Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

Does this have to do with writing permissions of shiny? I've already spent a good chunk of time researching but no luck. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
Code: 
library(shiny)

# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <- c("name", "dog", "food")

# Save a response
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage 
type ----
saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
```

}

```
# Load all previous responses
# ---- This is one of the two functions we will change for every storage 
type ----
loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}

# Shiny app with 3 fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    textInput("dog", "what is your favorite dog?"),
    textInput("food", "favorite food?"),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

# Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

# When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

# Show the previous responses
# (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })     
    outputDir <- "C:/Users/tolson/Desktop/Shiny"

    saveData <- function(data) {
      data <- t(data)
      # Create a unique file name
      fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv", as.integer(Sys.time()), 
digest::digest(data))
      # Write the file to the local system
      write.csv(
        x = data,
        file = file.path(outputDir, fileName), 
        row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE
      )
    }

    loadData <- function() {
       # Read all the files into a list
      files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)
      data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
      data <- do.call(rbind, data)
      data
    }





     }
 )
```

Comment: The server on shinyapps.io cannot just write files to your desktop. However, you can use Dropbox instead as outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/philchalmers/5946009031ed9ffb7304)

Comment: Thank you @GregordeCillia much appreciated.